# Ruby followers query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

We have an SQL query in our Rails 3 app.

`@followers` returns an array of IDs of users following the `current_user`.

```
@followers = current_user.following
@feed_items = Micropost.where("belongs_to_id IN (?)", @followers)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this query?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this inefficient or not suitable?

Comment: future scalability concerns in terms of query speed

Answer (score 3):

The query you have can't really be optimized anymore than it is. It could be made faster by adding an index to `belongs_to_id` (which you should almost always do for foreign keys anyway), but that doesn't change the actual query.

There is a cleaner way to write `IN` queries though:

```
Micropost.where(:belongs_to_id => @followers)
```

where `@followers` is an array of values for `belongs_to_id`.

Comment: +1 (sigh) Yup, that's even cleaner than mine.  Had to up-vote ya Andrew ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me.

However if you're looking for real minimum numer of characters in the code, you could change:

`Micropost.where("belongs_to_id IN (?)", @followers)`
to
`Micropost.where("belongs_to_id = ?", @followers)`

which reads a little easier.

Rails will see the array and do the `IN`.

As always the *main* goal of the ruby language is readability so little improvements help.

As for query being inefficent, you shuld check into indexs on that field.
They tend to be a little more specific for each db - you have only specified generic sql. in your question.